# Cannot access my exposed service with nodeIP:nodePort in AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster with only private subnets, i tried to expose a simple nginx service on nodePort and then check this url private-node-ip:nodePort on the browser but its showing **this site can't be reached**

here is my code :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: http
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Comment: Please share the output of the command `kubectl get svc -owide`. From where are you trying to reach your service? Since the nodePort will expose a port from the node, you need to have make sure you can reach your instance from the test side. Since it is a private network, you only will be able to reach the service from a instance in the same network, or if you have a VPN configured.

Answer (score 1):

Your `port: 80` value for the NodePort is outside the default allowable range (30000 to 32767) on kubernetes. This range can be changed, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752821/how-to-set-service-node-port-range-and-then-be-able-to-deploy-services-using-the) but I don't think you can expose the low port numbers with NodePort, though I'm open to correction. Hope this helps.

Edit - I misread the question above, and my original answer is incorrect. If your service had said `NodePort: 80`, then the range would have been an issue.

But, reading your question again, NodePort is usually exposed for a public IP. If your cluster doesn't have a public IP, then the machine where you're browsing from will need to be on the same private network as your cluster. It won't be exposed to the public Internet. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/518) for some discussion on the issue.

Comment: my NodePort is exposed randomly on 30242 but i don't know how to allow traffic for that range of port on CLI since all tutorials are doing it on the console

Comment: Can you use your console to show the details of your svc? Or is there some way of checking your cluster info to make sure that there isn't some exposed URL - like the kube master address?

Comment: But if there's no node on your cluster that you can access publicly, then you have the issue I described above, that you'll need to be on the same network (via VPN or otherwise) to access nginx at that port via your browser.

Comment: I don't know much about AWS, but I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/faun/learning-kubernetes-by-doing-part-3-services-ed5bf7e2bc8e). It mentions, among other things, having to add inbound rules to nodes via the console. This might fix your issue?