# is it possible to put fixed ip and port in minikube?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

it is possible to fix the ip and port somewhere in my yaml.
My application has 3 parts: a fronted with its respective balancer, a backend with its respective balancer and the database with statefulset and to persevere the volume, these 3 applications have their respective hpa rules.

I put the yaml of the backend if it is possible to set the ip and the port since I am working local and every so often I have to change the port or the ip.

backend.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: XXXXXXX
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args: ["-c", "node index.js"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: HOST_DB
              value: "172.17.0.3"
            - name: PORT_DB
              value: "31109"
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
            limits:
              memory: "256Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 4000
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 4000
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 20

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 4000
      name: https
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: backend
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 50
```

the result image is this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The IP is anyway fixed to the single node's IP in case of minikube.You can hardcode the `NodePort` by specifying `nodePort` in the service. Without `nodePort` specified in the service kubernetes will assign a port from the range `30000-32767`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 4000
      name: https
      nodePort: 30007
```

Follow this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/) to expose applications via `NodePort` type service in minikube.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to respond, I have some questions.
1.- if I put the nodeport I will not be able to use loadbalancing?
2.- how do I set the ports since I will only have 3 services (front-end, back-end and database)

Comment: LoadBalancer type service does not work in minikube anyway.

Comment: LoadBalancer type exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer. So it works if you are running the cluster on a cloud provider

Comment: but isn't minikube a cloud cluster simulator? and how do I restrict the ports? Thanks for answering me

Comment: By cloud provider I meant AWS, GCP, Azure etc. You want to restrict port or hardcode port?

Comment: restrict port 30000-30010

Comment: @SilvioPeña You can restrict nodeport range in kubernetes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752821/how-to-set-service-node-port-range-and-then-be-able-to-deploy-services-using-the