# Kubernetes:Confluence setup: editor not connecting, synchrony checks ok

Tags: kubernetes, confluence

I have a test setup with two machines:

nginx reverse proxy: (running on physical machine 1)

- /confluence --> http://<node-ip>:30890
- /synchrony --> http://<node-ip>:30891

kubernetes: (running on physical machine 2)

- my understanding of kubernetes networking:
  software defined network, IPs are allocated dynamically,
  machines/pods and services are identified by tags / name
- service: confluence
  type: NodePort
  confluence-pod:8090 --> node:30890
  confluence-pod:8091 --> node:30891
- pod: confluence (actually a deployment generating a pod)
  port: 8090
  synchrony: 8091

I pass all the tests mentioned here [in Confluence docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/how-to-check-the-status-of-synchrony-for-confluence-data-center-953651062.html). However the confluence editor is not able to connect.

Should I

a) configure confluence to run on 30890/30891 already in the pod?
b) change kubernetes default port range? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763328/3008308 
c) know of a confluence config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c) I should know about Confluence:

- ARM is not officially supported.
- Confluence depends on snappy, a native compression library.
- the editor didn't fail to connect because of Kubernetes, but because of unsupported architecture (= misconfigured snappy library)

I solved it by installing `libsnappy-java` and its native components directly on the machine.

https://bitbucket.org/lukastreyer/docker-atlassian-confluence-server/src/master/